# Protecting Python Script (PyQGIS) Code from Unauthorized Access/Reading in QGIS Console

Tags: python, vpn, obfuscation, vps, pyqgis

I'm a GIS professional with knowledge in Python, SQL, JavaScript, and Esri Arcade. While I have experience using these languages for tasks such as calculations, task automation, Excel automation, reporting, and data analysis, I haven't delved into developing complex systems with access controls. However, I'm now facing the challenge of protecting a Python script I'm working on for QGIS. This script contains sensitive information related to my company's workflows, and I want to prevent it from falling into the wrong hands, particularly competitors or unauthorized users.

Initially, I considered creating plugins; however, I realized that even with plugins, someone could still copy the underlying script. Therefore, I'm exploring the option of storing the scripts on a Virtual Private Server (VPS). However, I'm uncertain about the process of setting up the server to ensure that only I, as the root user, have access to the scripts, and how the paths will be defined (IP + folder).

Additionally, I would like to have a straightforward way to manage user access, especially when someone leaves the company and needs to be removed from the system. While I trust my team, I want to eliminate any potential risks and prevent the distribution of scripts to competitors. Unfortunately, I don't have anyone with an IT background within the company to consult with, which makes it more challenging.

Here's what I have in mind:

here is what i was thinking to do: script1.py to be saved on the VPS (it is ubuntu server managed by Contabo and currently I am accesing it by remote desktop, or from SSH with PuTTy).

```
import all dependencies

processing_function(inputs):
...
...
```

Script2.py will be sent to each colleague working on the project and will be set up as follows (I found this as an example on the internet, but I'm not sure how to set up my script path and server):

```
layers =  QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()
for layer in layers:
    if layer.name() == "Roads":
        roads_layer = layer
    if layer.name() == "Fences":
        fences_layer = layer
    if layer.name() == "Road Label":
        r_label_layer = layer       
    if layer.name() == "Trees":
        trees_layer = layer

scriptpath = "//server IP/QGIS_Scripts"
scriptpath_local = "c:/Automation/Scripts"

sys.path.append(scriptpath)
sys.path.append(scriptpath_local)

import script1
import script2
script2.function()

print ("Complete")
```

Furthermore, I'd like to manage user access effectively. However, with my limited knowledge in VPNs and similar setups, I have no idea how to configure access for users who work both from home and the office (we have a hybrid work policy with 2 days in the office and 3 days from home). While we have static IPs in the office, dynamic IPs are used when working remotely. Do you have any suggestions or ideas?

I would greatly appreciate any help or advice on how to achieve these goals in a simple and straightforward manner. Thank you all for your valuable assistance!